# jQuery: Recalculating browser width after resize

Tags: jquery, resize

I have this short script which positions a div on the right side of my screen.
Everything works fine until I resize my browser.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var width = $(window).width();
    var height = $(window).height();

    $('.boxright').css({"left": width -500 + "px"});

});
```

My question now: How can I recalculate the browser width after a resize?
I know there is `$(window).resize` but my coding skills are too limited to get it working,
so it would be really great if anyone could provide some working lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the code in a function, so that you can call it both when the page loads and when the page resizes:

```
function setSize() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  $('.boxright').css({"left": width -500 + "px"});
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  setSize();
});

$(window).resize(setSize);
```

You might also consider to simply align the element with the right edge instead of the left, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.boxright').css({"right": "200px"});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **[resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)** like what you describe in your question:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();

        $('.boxright').css({"left": width -500 + "px"});
    });

});
```

Comment: Hmm, this only positions the div AFTER a resize, but not when the site is loaded the first time. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Tbyas You can put it in a function and call it on page load, I think Guffa's answer is what you're looking for